# Вопрос по выводу их двух таблиц MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Добрый день. Преамбула:
Есть 2 таблицы "law_menu" и "law_content".
В "law_menu" есть колонка, где хранятся данные о сcылке на данные bp таблицы "law_content". Ссылки типа

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10
```

Итак, есть самописный модуль, где я вывожу данные из таблицы "law_content" благодаря id из этой ссылки

```
<?php
include "php/dbc.php";
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'", $dbcnx);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME, $dbcnx);

$news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM law_menu WHERE parent = 27 AND ordering <> 21 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($news)) {
    echo "<a class='bankmoduleid_".$row['id']."' href='".$row['reallink']."'>";

    $parts = parse_url($row['link']);
    parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
    $bank_id = $query['id'];

    $new = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM law_content WHERE id = $bank_id");
    while($bankid=mysql_fetch_assoc($new)) {
        echo "<img src='/images/".$bank_id."' />".$row['name']."</a>";
    }
}
mysql_close($dbcnx);
?>
```

Внизу переменная "$bank_id" прекрасно выводи мне необходимые id.
Но мне нужно вывести значение колонки "logo_pic", сответствующее этому "id"

**Спасибо заранее!**

Comment: вы бы указали где конкретно у вас выводится нормально, а где не работает. Т.к. "внизу" понятие не очень понятное. Видно что в `bank_id` в конце у вас попадет массив из строки БД. Вам в картинке надо вывести что-то вида `$bank_id['logo_pic']` или что?

Comment: речь о строке - 
echo "<img src='/images/".$bank_id."' />".$row['name']."</a>";
............ К примеру, если $bank_id = 100, то мне нужно там отобразить значение logo_pic при id = 100 из таблицы law_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш запрос `$new = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM law_content WHERE id = $bank_id");` извлекает всю строку таблицы для соответствующего `id`. Далее в цикле `while` содержимое строк бд целиком попадет в переменную `$bankid`.

Поэтому для вывода искомой строки используйте выражение:

```
echo "<img src='/images/".$bank_id['logo_pic]."' />".$row['name']."</a>";
```

Обратите внимание, что у вас есть две переменных, `$bank_id` и `$bankid`, в одной идентификатор, а в другой соответствующая ему строка.

Comment: Да .. именно это решение мне и нужно было. Благодарю !

Comment: @berTalino ответы, которые подходят, обычно отмечают как [Правильные](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)